# Retrofit Returns Required Value parks missing at $ When I do not have main element on JSON

Tags: android, retrofit2

Summary: I am trying to pull data from National Parks (API) and it has JSON that does not have main element name.  And it seems retrofit looks at variable name for finding element automatically. It fails returning an error 'Required Value parks missing at $'.  I do not have parks but I am not looking for parks element at all. I searched through stackoverflow to see if anyone has similar issue and did not find so I am posting this question here.

Detail: Here is the json from API...

```
{"total":"498","data":[{"contacts":{"phoneNumbers":[{"phoneNumber":"9372257705","description":"","extension":"","type":"Voice"}],"emailAddresses":[{"description":"","emailAddress":"tom_engberg@nps.gov"}]},"states":"OH","longitude":"-84.0711364746094","activities":[{"id":"B33DC9B6-0B7D-4322-BAD7-A13A34C584A3","name":"Guided Tours"}],"entranceFees":[{"cost":"1.0000","description":"The National Aviation Heritage Area is comprised of many sites. While some sites are free of charge to the public, others may have entrance fees and\/or event or participation fees. Please check on the specific National Aviation Heritage Area site prior to your visit.","title":"Entrance Fees Vary"}],"directionsInfo":"The National Aviation Heritage Area has multiple sites located throughout eight counties in the Dayton, Ohio and western Ohio area. Please be sure to visit a specific National Aviation Heritage Area website for directions and\/or maps to each location.","entrancePasses":[{"cost":"1.0000","description":"The National Aviation Heritage Area is comprised of many sites. While some sites are free of charge to the public, others may have entrance fees and\/or event or participation fees. Please check on the specific National Aviation Heritage Area site prior to your visit.","title":"Fee Pass Costs Vary"}],"directionsUrl":"http:\/\/www.aviationheritagearea.org\/","url":"https:\/\/www.nps.gov\/avia\/index.htm","weatherInfo":"The National Aviation Heritage Area lies in a humid continental zone with a generally temperate climate. Winters are mildly cold with average temperatures around 39 degrees (F). Summers are hot and humid with an average temperature around 74 degrees (F). Average annual total rainfall is just above 41\". Snowfall in the winter is generally light with an average total snowfall of about 25\".","name":"National Aviation","operatingHours":[{"exceptions":[],"description":"While this website is not meant to be an exhaustive resource for all of the National Aviation Heritage Area partners and organizations, there is an official partner organization (National Aviation Heritage Alliance) which operates a separate and full-functioning website with a plethora of site information. Visit National Aviation Heritage Alliances' webpage for up-to-date information, directions and breaking news for all of the historical sites and member organizations.","standardHours":{"wednesday":"All Day","monday":"All Day","thursday":"All Day","sunday":"All Day","tuesday":"All Day","friday":"All Day","saturday":"All Day"},"name":"Various Heritage Area Sites"}],"topics":[{"id":"B912363F-771C-4098-BA3A-938DF38A9D7E","name":"Aviation"}],"latLong":"lat:39.9818229675293, long:-84.0711364746094","description":"Aviation is chock-full of tradition & history and nowhere will you find a richer collection of aviation than here, the birthplace of aviation.  From the straightforward bicycle shops that fostered the Wright brothers' flying ambitions to the complex spacecraft that carried man to the moon, the National Aviation Heritage Area has everything you need to learn about this country’s aviation legacy.","images":[{"credit":"NPS Photo \/ Tom Engberg","altText":"Visitor center building in background with plaza in foreground","title":"Dayton's National Park","caption":"The Wright-Dunbar Interpretive Center located just west of downtown Dayton","url":"https:\/\/www.nps.gov\/common\/uploads\/structured_data\/DCB2628F-1DD8-B71B-0BD78D1063069C70.jpg"}],"designation":"Heritage Area","parkCode":"avia","addresses":[{"postalCode":"45402","city":"Dayton","stateCode":"OH","line1":"16 South Williams St.","type":"Physical","line3":"","line2":""},{"postalCode":"45402","city":"Dayton","stateCode":"OH","line1":"16 South Williams St.","type":"Mailing","line3":"","line2":""}],"id":"C8C207D8-49C4-4891-9915-0007205A0284","fullName":"National Aviation Heritage Area","latitude":"39.9818229675293"}],"limit":"1","start":"1"}
```

The following is the data class i wrote:

```
data class NetworkParkContainer(val parks: List<NetworkPark>)
data class NetworkPark(
    val data: List<Data>,
    val limit: String,
    val start: String,
    val total: String
)
```

Here is the code that I called to get the JSON data:

```
interface ParksApiService {
    companion object {
        val API_KEY = "<my own api key value>"
    }
    @GET("parks")
    suspend fun getParks(@Query("api_key") type: String, @Query("limit") limit: Int): NetworkParkContainer
}
```

Why would Retrofit 2 look for 'parks'? There is no 'parks' in any of my data class at all. It seems it looks at 'parks' in :

```
data class NetworkParkContainer(val parks: List<NetworkPark>)
```

How would I tell retrofit that I want all of it like I wrote data class NetworkPark that does not even include 'parks'?

Here is the API path:
https://developer.nps.gov/api/v1/parks?api_key=&limit=1

My base URL is https://developer.nps.gov/api/v1/

So my @GET is parks so therefore, it should come out like that
https://developer.nps.gov/api/v1/parks?api_key=&limit=1

Comment: Return `NetworkPark` from `getParks` not `NetworkParkContainer` .. `NetworkParkContainer` is useless in this case ..

Comment: @ADM Thank you. You are right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data class is doing wrong mapping. You need to make sure that your keys from the API are the same name that the data class has as GSON uses these values, not retrofit. Retrofit simply fetches the data and then passes it to GSON for deserialization. If API returns weird names and you do not want that in your data classes then use **@SerializedName("newName: String")** annotation on the parameter in the data class.

## SOLUTION

```
data class NetworkPark(
  val total: String,
  val data: List<Data>,
  val limit: String,
  val start: String
)
```

This data class is redundant:

```
data class NetworkParkContainer(val parks: List<NetworkPark>)
```

Changes in the interface:

```
interface ParksApiService {
companion object {
    val API_KEY = "<my own api key value>"
}

@GET("parks")
suspend fun getParks(@Query("api_key") type: String, @Query("limit") limit: Int): NetworkPark
}
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solve your question. Thank you :)